# Is $\omega_\alpha$ a limit ordinal for any $\alpha\neq0$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

In the 3th chapter of the book "Teoria de Conjunto (Curso intermedio)" by José Alfredo, Amor Montaño, Gabriela Campero Arena, Favio Ezequiel and Miranda Perea, 
having defined the set $CAR=\{k\colon k\text{ is a cardinal and } k\geq\omega\}$, I've read that "if $k\in CAR$ then $k$ is a limit ordinal" and to demonstrate this the text proceeds through the following arguments:"Be that $k\in CAR$. If $k$ were a successor ordinal, say $k=\alpha+1$, then a bijection of $k$ can be found with the previous ordinal, that is $k\sim\alpha$.  But then $\alpha<k$, which contradicts the fact that $k$ is cardinal. To give the bijection $k\sim\alpha$ is left as an exercise for the reader."

What would be the bijection between $k=\alpha+1$ and $\alpha$?

Then supposing that if $\lambda\neq0$ is a limit ordinal, then $1+\lambda=\lambda$, I found the function $\phi:k\to\alpha$ defined as

$$\phi(\beta)=\begin{cases} 0, &\text{ if }\beta=\alpha \\ 1+\beta, &\text{ if }\beta\neq\alpha\end{cases}$$

Is the function $\phi$ a bijection between $k=\alpha+1$ and $\alpha$?

How to prove that $\phi$ is surjective onto $\alpha$?

Comment: Even $\omega_0$ is a limit ordinal ($\omega_0=\omega$).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understeand. Could you explain better?

Comment: $\omega_0$ is just $\omega$, which is an infinite limit ordinal (indeed the smallest infinite ordinal). Your title restricts to $\alpha\not=0$, but that's not necessary.

Comment: If $\alpha\geq\omega$ fix a countable subset $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$ of $\alpha$ and consider the function $f\colon\alpha+1\to\alpha$ sending $\alpha$ to $a_1$, $a_n$ to $a_{n+1}$ and everything else to itself. $f$ is a bijection between $\alpha+1$ and $\alpha$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, much more is true *(and I think this is a situation where stating only the weaker result makes it look more mysterious)*:

> For any infinite ordinal $\theta$ at all - limit or otherwise - we have $1+\theta=\theta$ in the sense of [ordinal addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Addition) (and so a fortiori there is a bijcetion between $1+\theta$ and $\theta$).

This is an argument by transfinite induction *starting at $\omega$*:

- The base case $\theta=\omega$ is basically [Hilbert's Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel).
- The successor step follows by applying the induction hypothesis twice ($(\theta+1)+1\rightarrow\theta+1\rightarrow\theta$).
- As a hint for the limit step, remember that by definition for $\lambda$ limit we have $$1+\lambda=\sup_{\beta<\lambda}(1+\beta).$$ Now think about what the induction hypothesis will say about the $(1+\beta)$s ...

So in fact your map can be more simply described as:

- $\varphi(\alpha)=0$,
- for $n\in\omega$, $\varphi(n)=1+n$, and
- for $\omega<\beta<\alpha$ we set $\varphi(\beta)=\beta$.

This is much easier to think about, and in particular it's easy to see that this is surjective.

Comment: Okay, however I continue to have doubts about the surjectivity in the event that $\alpha$ is an initial (infinite) ordinal of the type $\omega_1$.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Why? (The result is still true.) Also, note that "initial (infinite) ordinal of the type $\omega_1$" is just $\omega_1$.

Comment: Okay, I'll think about it.

Comment: Note that **for any** infinite $\alpha$ the map $\varphi: \alpha+1\rightarrow\alpha$ given as in my answer is by definition the identity on all infinite elements of $\alpha+1$ other than $\alpha$. So to check surjectivity we just need to show $\omega\subseteq ran(\varphi)$ since we trivially have $\beta\in ran(\varphi)$ for $\beta\in\alpha\setminus\omega$.

Comment: But this is straightforward: if $n\in\omega$ is nonzero then $n=\varphi(n-1)$, and if $n=0$ then $n=\varphi(\alpha)$. So - again, regardless of what $\alpha$ is - the map $\varphi$ defined in my answer is a bijection between $\alpha+1$ and $\alpha$.